# Rich Text Editor On browser, other than nicEdit, tinyMCE, non-jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a non-jQuery based Rich Text Editor for my web application. I did try nicEdit and it has cross-browser issues, especially with firefox.
We are writing application level javascript code as well, comparing the values in the RTE , diasbling/enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

Other well-known browser-based RTEs include:

- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
- [Aloha](http://aloha-editor.org/)

Comment: Thank you. Shall try them out and get back.